# Unable to pass data from popup Modal to parent page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a popup modal in angularjs. In the popup there are input fields which should form table by the input values.
There are two HTML pages.
First Html page is a parent page which contains a button that redirects to popup page
Second html page is the popup containing one text field
Entering value in that text field should form rows with two input fields
Upon taking input from formed input fields and clicking ok.
Popup should close and table should be formed in the parent page.
Below is the plnkr to get a detailed idea.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/z2E9sE

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
      controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        debugger;
        $scope.table = 0;
   $scope.cols = [];
   $scope.rows = [];

   $scope.makeArray = function() {
      if ($scope.table) {
        return new Array(parseInt($scope.table));
      } else {
        return new Array(0);
      }
   }

   $scope.gen=function($index)
   {
     $scope.getColsCount($index);
     $scope.getRowsCount($index);
    
   };
     $scope.getRowsCount = function ($index) {
      if ($scope.rows[$index]) {
         return new Array(parseInt($scope.rows[$index]));
      } else {
         return new Array(0);
      }
   }

   $scope.getColsCount = function ($index) {
      if ($scope.cols[$index]) {
        return new Array(parseInt($scope.cols[$index]));
      } else {
        return new Array(0);
      }
    }
        $scope.ok = function() {
          debugger;
          $uibModalInstance.close($scope.gen());
        };
        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        };
      },
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = `${response} `;
    });
  };
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.*" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.6.*" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-touch@1.6.*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open()" style="margin: 15px;">Create Shelf</button>
      
      
       <table ng-repeat="t in makeArray() track by $index">
        <tr ng-repeat="r in getRowsCount($index) track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="c in getColsCount($parent.$index) track by $index">Col </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```html
<h3> POP UP</h3>
<input ng-model="table" type="number" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in makeArray() track by $index">
        <td> <input ng-model="rows[$index]" type="number" />
        </td>
        <td> <input ng-model="cols[$index]" type="number" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the question above.
The code is posted below.
Here is the Plunker link.
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/z2E9sE

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
app.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal) {
    $rootScope.tableArray = [];
    $rootScope.getRowsCountData = [];
    $rootScope.getColsCountData = [];
    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                $scope.tableCount = 0;
                $scope.tables = [];
                $scope.cols = [];
                $scope.rows = [];
                $rootScope.tableArray = [];
                $rootScope.getRowsCountData = [];
                $rootScope.getColsCountData = [];
                $scope.makeArray = function () {
                    if ($scope.tableCount) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.tableCount; i++)
                        {
                            let obj = { rows: 0, cols: 0 };
                            $scope.tables.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $scope.ok = function () {
                     $rootScope.tableArray = $scope.tables;
                    
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                };
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
                };
            },
        });
    };
});
app.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);

        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }

        return input;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.*" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.6.*" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-touch@1.6.*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="plunker">
    <script id="modalContent.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <h3> POP UP</h3>
        <input ng-model="tableCount" type="number" ng-change="makeArray()" />
    
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="t in tables track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="t.rows" type="number" />
                </td>
                <td> <input ng-model="t.cols" type="number" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
           <!-- <table ng-repeat="t in makeArray() track by $index">
          <tr ng-repeat="r in getRowsCount($index) track by $index">
            <td ng-repeat="c in getColsCount($parent.$index) track by $index">Col </td>
          </tr>
        </table> -->
        <pre>{{tableArray}}</pre>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open()" style="margin: 15px;">Create Shelf</button>

      <pre>{{tableArray}}</pre>
        <table ng-repeat="t in tableArray track by $index" border="2">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in [] | range:t.rows">
                <td ng-repeat="c in [] | range:t.cols">RC</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things happening here. 
First: you're not returning anything in your gen function, or passing an index when calling it.
Second: be aware that the modal is creating a seperate scope, your makeArray function is declared on the scope of the modal.
Here's an updated [plnkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/858UMCsGIf8t8IoV)  that should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please refer this jsfiddle link for my detailed problem
https://jsfiddle.net/iamsaisanthosh/r1zync3g/53/

There is no popup in the above link provided
I need to take input from popup and form table outside popup